# Dell has plenty of Ubuntu Certified Hardware, but the XPS that ships with Ubuntu isn't on the list. Why not?

Tags: hardware-certification

https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?release=16.04%20LTS&category=Laptop

Why isn't the XPS13 on this list? It ships WITH Ubuntu, why wouldn't it be "Certified".

Answer (score 2):

In the link you provided enable the following options:

1. Laptops
2. preinstalled by manufacturer
3. 14.04 LTS
4. Dell

Then click the `Update`-button and you will find the XPS13 on page 5.

[certification.ubuntu.com](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?category=Laptop&level=Enabled&vendors=Dell&release=14.04+LTS&query=&page=5)

Comment: Ok, so what about the 7th gen CPUs that ship with 16.04? 9360 I think is the model number.

Comment: @GreenFox You are right, XPS13 9360 ships with 16.04 (checked on Dell-website) and is not on the list. Maybe this model is very new and certification.ubuntu.com not updated yet. Maybe it is not certified yet, I don't know how long such a certify-process takes.